# Is there a setting to force user stories to be linked to a parent?

Tags: azure-devops

There is a setting for forcing story points to be entered when creating a work item (e.g. user story) in the layout processes field options, but is there one for mandating linking of work item/story to a parent?

[image: story points option]

[image: parent]

Comment: Maybe a rule can enforce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a straight forward way to do that.

A good option is to create a custom field in User Story work item in your inherited process.

[image]

And set the work item rule to make required the value of this field when creating User Stroy.

[image]

Check the UI output by using the rule. This could be a reminder to link the parent work item.

[image]

**Update 1:**

You still need to manually add link as Related Work.

The required value for the custom field works as a reminder for the users when creating the User Story.

[image]

You could also define the custom field as Picklist(string). When a user creates a new User Story, he could add Related Work links and pick a value for the custom field in order to save this User Story.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but where is the related work field then? It appears it would be removed in this scenario and replaced with this custom field? Because what if the creator of the story want to link tasks for example

Comment: Hello Cataster, I have updated the answer with a sample.

Comment: I see, I guess this may work. Btw, is there a way to require updating the user story at least once a day? Since we care about the burn down charts, we dont want user story creators to forget their assigned user stories, so they should frequently be adding either a comment or changing the activity state. A query for just the state though wouldnt be accurate because you might be working on a story still and the state could be anything, I was thinking tracking the changed date and creating a logic app to send a message to a user as reminder, but is there a better way just like this parent rule?